# Unexpected end of file while looking for `" script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to execute a bash script and getting the "Unexpected EOF while looking for matching ' " ' error. Not sure where I'm messing up.

The script is designed to insert .md files as entries into a journal program. The journal program uses the following CLI code to insert each .md file: 'dayone2 -d="YYYY-MM-DD TT:TT" new < "filename". So the script extracts the date from the filename itself and runs the program as above.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# October 11, 2015 - John Raymonds
#
for file in *.md
do
# do something on "$file"
year="$(echo "$file" | cut -c 13,14,15,16)"
day="$(echo "$file" | cut -c 18,19)"
month="$(echo "$file" | cut -c 21,22)"
theDate=\"$year"-"$month"-"$day" 12:00PM"\"
#The date should end up in this format "2017-01-24 12:00PM"

/usr/local/bin/dayone2 -d="$theDate" new < "$file"

rm "$file"
done
```

Where is the code wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

The quoting on `theDate` is wrong. It should be:

`theDate="${year}-${month}-${day} 12:00PM"`

When assigning to a string variable, you're better off with just a single pair of surrounding double-quotes, and using the `${}` syntax to disambiguate your variable names.

Comment: The `{}` isn't needed in this case as the `-` character would properly end the name of the variable.  `$year-` would be expanded into the value of `$year` directly followed by a dash.

Comment: @Kusalananda: true, but I wanted to give him an example that was clear as to how to do it so it always works.  `$year-` will work and `$year_` won't, and that distinction will be very tough for a beginner to do a web search for.